# Failed to link a domain from Namecheap with a bucket on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to connect my domain registered in Namecheap to my S3 buckets.

I've checked many questions related to this in here but my configuration seems to be ok.

I'm able to access the website through the static website endpoint provided by AWS (http://masahiro-takechi.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/engineer_portfolio_resume/index.html)
but when I enter my custom domain in the browser, it takes a long while to load and finally says the page could not be loaded.

I have two buckets and masahiro-takechi.com is my main bucket.

[image]

And these three pics below are some important settings from masahiro-takechi.com bucket.
[image]

[image]
[image]

And these are from [www.masahiro-takechi.com](http://www.masahiro-takechi.com).
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also, here is a screenshot on Namecheap dashboard page.

[image]

Comment: Do you think I need to delete the folder called "engineer_portfolio_resume" inside the the masahiro-takechi.com bucket??

Comment: Can you move your website out of the `engineer_portfolio_resume` folder?